# Where i can check my application api (request response time ) logs in google cloud project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud project and i want to see the logs of all api hits request and response parameters in GCP. In AWS we have S3 browser to get all logs folder. What is the equivalent in GCP??

Answer (score 1):

In GCP logs are not stored on a filesystem, there is no `logs folder`, so "equivalent" is a bit relative.

Most (if not all) GCP products funnel their logs through [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/), which offer a somewhat consistent interface for [viewing](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) and/or further processing/exporting them (see [Basic Concepts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/basic-concepts)).

The structure and content/details of a particular log entry depends on the log type and the particular GCP product that produced it (and/or its flavour). For App Engine the environment being used, for example, matters for the log entry content ([1st generation standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/), [2nd generation standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs) or [flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs)).

At least for the 1st generation standard environment (which I use) the request response times (and all other parameters logged/available for all requests and their corresponding replies) are captured in the [request logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/#understanding_request_log_fields):

> 11    Wallclock time  Yes
>
> Total clock time in milliseconds spent by App Engine on the request.
>   This time duration does not include time spent between the client and
>   the server running the instance of your application. Example: ms=195.